# Link, activeClassName just plain not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I cannot get `activeClassName` to render correctly in my Navigation component Link. This has been tracked down to the following symptoms:

In the following code, the Navigation component is not getting a `props.route` passed to it at all. The App component has a `props.route`, however it is never updated as the user navigates to other routes. It is always set to the first route that was loaded. The `componentWillReceiveProps` is fired when changing routes, as the `props.children` is changing.

Here are the relevant snippets of my files:

**app.jsx**

```
import router from 'app/router';

[...]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {router}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**router/index.jsx**

```
export default (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={GameBoard}/>
      <Route path="profile" component={ProfileBoard}/>
      <Route path="profile/:userId" component={ProfileBoard}/>
      <Route path="help" component={Help}/>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from 'Navigation';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <div className="content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**Navigation.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {IndexLink, Link} from 'react-router';


export class Navigation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="top-bar navigation">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="small-12 columns">
            <div className="top-bar-left">
              <ul className="menu">
                <li className="menu-text">
                  TVDeadpool.xyz
                </li>
                <li>
                  <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="link-active">Bets</IndexLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/help" activeClassName="link-active">Help</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/about" activeClassName="link-active">About</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Navigation);
```

Navigation.jsx has been simplified. I removed some functionality that shows a Logout link if you are logged in, and handles that link. That is the reason I am including `connect`, though.

I am pouring through the documentation for react-router but cannot for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong. It must be something to do with nesting within the `<Provider/>`, I guess? Any help would be appreciated!

Note that if you want to see this in (in)action, check out [TVDeadpool.xyz](https://tvdeadpool.xyz). Not a plug, just a fact.

**UPDATE**

Here is a hack fix:

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from 'Navigation';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation location={this.props.location.pathname}/>
        <div className="content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Simply adding that `location` prop to `<Navigation/>` causes a re-render, without any additional code.

I think the reason this is happening is that App is always considered to be at `route.path` of "/", no matter what route is actually showing. Its immediate children seem to get the appropriate `route.path`, but Navigation, being a nested component of App, does not. In fact, it does not receive a `route` prop at all because it is not directly referenced by a `<Route/>`.

That said, how would this ever work? Should you not be able to simple include Link and expect it to work as described? I feel like I am missing something key to how react-router is supposed to work.

Comment: What's your react and react-router versions?

Comment: react@0.14.8 react-router@2.4.1

Comment: Try removing the leading slash from your `Link`s (not the `IndexLink` one)

Comment: I have indeed tried that, in fact the current code does not have those forward slashes. No help.

Comment: can you provide the value for `this.props.route.path`?

Comment: Here is the whole object: `"{"path":"/","indexRoute":{},"childRoutes":[{"path":"profile"},{"path":"profile/:userId"},{"path":"help"},{"path":"about"}]}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114984/discussion-between-chris-and-craig-wright).

Comment: Just a quick sanity check, is Navigation.jsx getting re-rendered when a link is clicked?  I would assume so, but wouldn't hurt to rule that out.

Comment: It is not! Not sure why. Updating question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason activeClassName is not working is because you are using connect 
`export default connect()(Navigation);`

See this issue... https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/388

It is reported as fixed in React Router 3.0.0-alpha.1 and newer.

Another hack fix I found you can use in older versions of react router is to pass {pure : false} to tell connect it is not a pure component...

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(Navigation);
```

Comment: The {pure: false} thing worked for me. This was an annoying one to resolve!